# What happens if `grid-column-start` and `grid-column-end` both has a `span` value?

Tags: css, css-grid

I saw https://tailwindcss.com/docs/grid-column has some classes that set both `grid-column-start` and `grid-column-end` to `span <number>`.

For example:

```
grid-column: span 3 / span 3;
```

I can't understand why it should be this, why not just say `grid-column-end: span3` instead? Is there any difference?

Comment: when using the same value, the system will remove one of them so you can consider them the same which is also equal to `grid-column: span 3;`
`

Comment: I think talwind is making such syntax to avoid you overriding the start or the end using another class. This will make sure it will span 3 columns